# Nginx remove '?' symbol before extension

Tags: regex, nginx

I managed to make my index.php script to run properly when I get a url like:

```
http://myserver.com/?something.m3u8
```

Still, I need to remove the `?` from it.

Any ideas?

My Nginx config looks like:

```
server {
listen 6868 default_server;

root /var/tmp/mfl;
index index.php;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: You have `return 403` at `server` block. Are you certain this configuration works as expected?..

Comment: Match the '?' with regex, then replace with an empty string.

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov Agh, you are right. I was testing some things and forgot to remove the line before posting it to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently is was an one line solution

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; #appended this line 
}
```